# Magento high load - multiple php index.php processes

Tags: magento

Is it normal for Magento to generate so many php processes?

I have high load at the moment being caused by around 25 php processes all from Magneto's index.php. They are all taking 20+% CPU according to top.

What could this be? According to Google Analytics there are only 10 active users online at the moment so not sure why I have so many php processes running?

How can find what all these processes are actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is very resource hungry and you have to tailor your server config to the server you have in place and the available hardware. Would be useful if you posted your server setup, i.e. Nginx and PHP-FPM or Apache and PHP Prefork, worker etc.

If using apache you might need to play with your config settings with regards to;

StartServers
MinSpareServers
MaxSpareServers
ServerLimit
MaxClients

All of these settings will define the number of spawned processes you have running at once. Generally an apache process is spawned but left idle in a pool when not being used, and as a request comes in it then grabs an available spawned idle process to handle the request or it generates a new one if they are all in use. This is most likely what you are seeing with your top.

My normal deployment environment for Magento these days is Nginx and PHP-FPM. There are many articles discussing the pros and cons as well as some which allow you to determine the best settings to have for your server hardware. Take a look at http://nls.io/how-do-i-calculate-apache-maxclients/ for a guide on how to calculate what settings you should be using and also have a read of the white papers that magento have published with regards to performance.

Magento performance is a big topic and there is lots you can do to improve it such as putting in a reverse proxy cache like varnish or use full page caching to minimize server load.